# While loop just stopped working after about 4 weeks without issue

Tags: mysql

I've been referencing and using a stored While Loop for no problems, daily for around 4 weeks. A few days ago it just stopped working.

Ive tried running this with different tables with no help.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ukdatatable_route_loop (IN _date date) 
BEGIN 
SET @first = 1, @last = (
SELECT all_act
    FROM ukdatatable_input_ops
    WHERE date=_date
); 
WHILE(@first <= @last) 
DO 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO ukdatatable_input_daily (date)
    VALUES (_date);
    SET @first = @first + 1;
    END WHILE; 
END $$
```

The loop should lookup an integer from the table ukdatatable_input_ops and then run the loop, creating (new) the number of rows that is equal to the integer returned from the table in another table ukdatatable_input_daily

Is anyone able to help?

Tables involved;

```
CREATE TABLE `ukdatatable_input_daily` (
 `entry_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `aaa` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bbb` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ccc` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ddd` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `eee` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
 `arrival_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `departure_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `comments` text,
 `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'edit',
 `day` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=156856 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4


CREATE TABLE `ukdatatable_input_ops` (
 `entry_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `fff` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `ggg` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hhh` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `iiil` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `jjj` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `all_act` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: What does "stoped working" mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: What are the values in these tables currently. What is the result you get when you run `SELECT all_act
    FROM ukdatatable_input_ops
    WHERE date=_date` with the `_date` you are calling the procedure? Do you get any errors when you run `INSERT INTO ukdatatable_input_daily(<whateverdate>);` manually?

Comment: `@last = (
SELECT all_act
    FROM ukdatatable_input_ops
    WHERE date=_date
)` seams to be a issue.. MySQL user variable can only store one value if that query result into two records it will fail.

Comment: things don't just stop working at random. Something has happened. Either a code change, an environment change, or a data change where there is now some data which is incompatible with the code. You'll have to clarify exactly what the error is, and then that might give us - and you - a better idea of where to start looking

Comment: `LIMIT 1` for your select query ?

Comment: *"LIMIT 1 for your select query ? "* With ORDER BY i hope @Cid otherwise the results are still random..

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, with order by. I pointed the fact that there may be more than 1 result in that query

Comment: *"I pointed the fact that there may be more than 1 result in that query "* well i know @Cid with ORDER BY the results can still be random if the values aren't unique.. ideally you should be adding a column with primary or unique key in the ORDER BY to get 100% pure deterministic (fixed) results on every run.. Mine comment was more meant that anny record can be the "first" without deterministic (fixed) ORDER BY usage.

Comment: Well, we need the result of that query

Comment: Further to the comments; the select returns a value of 14 at the moment. Select works fine on its own. The procedure runs but doesn't actually INSERT into the second table.

Comment: @ADyson - That's why I'm so confused. Has worked fine for weeks and then just stopped the INSERT.

Comment: @Cid, only one value returns from the SELCT

Comment: well, again, what error or unexpected behaviour is happening? "stopped" isn't an error message or problem statement which can be fixed. It's far more instructive to know what it _is_ doing as opposed to what it _isn't_ doing. If you can't immediately see a problem, you'll have to debug it until you narrow down the issue. We can't access your environment, so we can't debug it, and as we have no idea what your data looks like or what your schema is, we can't work it out by hand either

Comment: @ADyson the new rows are not INSERTing into ukdatatable_input_daily

Comment: mine crystal bol just broke @ADyson otherwise i would have know i've already orderd a new one.

Comment: one possibility is ukdatatable_input_ops has no data.But this is trivial to debug with a few judicious select statements.

Comment: "the new rows are not INSERTing". Yes, we know, you already said that, more than once. But it's not enough information. Read my last comment again and then act on it please. Otherwise we cannot help you, however much we might like to.

Comment: @WillJeeves i advice you to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask yourself the answer if you would know how to help if you would read this question.. You would have to help us to reproduce your problem we can't do with this limited information..

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry all, please go gentle on me, thought I had read what to do and I'm very new to mySQL.

Comment: Should I just post the CREATE's in here?

Comment: @WillJeeves Since you get `14` back when you run your select, I suspect your issue isn't the first SELECT nor is it your WHILE loop. I suspect the issue is with your INSERT. Because you are using the `IGNORE` keyword in the `INSERT` it's skipping any errors that may pop. Remove that keyword, recompile your proc, and rerun. It will toss an error that will probably tell you exactly why it can't run that insert. If the error message and next steps are not immediately obvious to you, update the question here with the error message noting that you removed the `IGNORE` keyword and we can help more.

Comment: @JNevill thank you, will try that now

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for this, works fine without the IGNORE. I don't really understand why at the moment, but it points me clearly to right place to now look.